# Kali linux keyboard backlight turn off when every i restart my computer

Tags: kali-linux, keyboard

In Kali linux keyboard backlight turn off when every i reconnect my keyboard or restart my computer. To turn on backlight we have a dedicate backlight switch in keyboard, But it did not work on kali linux, but it works on windows.

To turn on keyboard backlight we have to open terminal :

```
Xset led on
```

But it turn off until i restart or reconnect my keyboard.

Comment: i dont understand

Comment: I'm guessing you're using Kali as a desktop OS. It isn't one at all, it's a specialized toolbox for pentesters and other security professionals. You should consider it a suite of applications, not a distro. In the context it's intended for things like keyboard backlight are quite irrelevant, I'm fairly certain Kali's repo doesn't even contain the necessary libraries and other files. Kali is most commonly run as a Virtual Machine or booted from USB when it's needed. Most of the issues with it can be resolved with just [Kali documentation](https://www.kali.org/docs).